Diagonalization of quadratic forms and partial derivatives
I have the quadratic form V= $x^2 + y^2 + xy -a(2x+y)$, which is the potential of a quantum particle. I have to find a change of variables such that I get a harmonic oscillator.
I tried originally to separe into $(x+ \frac{1}{2}(y-2a))^2 + \frac{3}{4}y^2 -a^2$, but I get cross terms in the second partial derivatives.
The solution seems to first make a change $x-a= \hat{x}, \hspace{0.5cm} \hat{y}=y$   that results in $x^2 + y^2 +xy$ , and then make yet another change:
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\hat{x}= \frac{u_1-u_2}{\sqrt{2}}\\[0.5cm]
\hat{y}= \frac{u_1+u_2}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
which turns out to keep the partial derivatives without cross terms.
My question is, is there any general way or type of change of variables that allows the derivatives of the Laplacian not to have cross terms? We lack the formal mathematical background,but I feel there is something going on here because the last change looks like two vectors rotated by 45 degrees.

Write $x^2+y^2+xy=(x,y)\begin{pmatrix}
1 &\frac{1}{2} \
\frac{1}{2}& 1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x \
y
\end{pmatrix}$ then diagonalize the matrix in the form $UDU^{-1}$. The matrix $U$ captures the rotation you notice. Now $\begin{pmatrix}
x' \
y'
\end{pmatrix} = U^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
x \
y
\end{pmatrix}$ and you can write the quadratic expression in terms of $x'$ and $y'$ then complete the square from there.

Why will the transformation matrix be unitary? Also, does the left row vector transform with U because it's a dual vector whose coordinates transform as the basis does?

U may not be unitary, U is just a letter. The matrix is symmetric though. No need to get bogged down in duals etc, just multiply the quadratic expression out..
